# about IDE, on clonning a github repository. issue: i require a "commit diff" to be cloned instead of the final project

Tags: django, github, ide, pycharm, git-fork

I will explain my own problem so it is easier to understand.

I have several books of Django, currently on Django Unleashed by Andrew Pinkham.

On the sample project files you have this straightforward project https://github.com/jambonrose/DjangoUnleashed-1.8/

I managed to fork it to my github and clone it on Pycharm professional IDE through its VCS/checkout from version control/github, so I can do certain stuff like right click stuff and see where it leads to within the project etc...

The issue I am finding, however is that when reading through the book as the code develops in each chapter, this code isn't saved in the whole parent branch divided by episodes, but it is instead saved as diff commmits, or steps of the process towards the final github project

I, for example can link to certain commits as [dju.link/a30e354253/organizer/views.py](http://dju.link/a30e354253/organizer/views.py)
but when I fork this to my account, only the final project which is up gets to my profile and ends up being cloned.

For example this final link to a commit I just put leads to a folder called blob which doesn't even exist when i look at the project
....github.com/jambonrose/DjangoUnleashed-1.8/**blob**/a30e354253/organizer/views.py

While a search for blob or a30e354253 on jambonrose's project wont turn anything

I would pretty much like Pycharm to open the whole project as it was on the moment of that commit if possible, so I could for example do a right click on let's say a URL pattern and see how far had it been developed as of that chapter.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

That GitHub URL shows `organizer/views.py` as it existed at the commit `a30e354253`.

To get that locally, use `git checkout <ref>` to check out the entire repo at that commit.

Comment: perfect, I will check it